# ng-repeat for nested array in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am getting data in nested array.

I am trying to display my data in this format

```
Jan

01 Mon newyear
13 sat bhogi
14 sun pongal

Feb

14 tue Valentine's day
```

Am little bit confused to loop it.

This is what I have tried

```
<table ng-repeat="list in holidayList" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    @*<th>{{list.}}</th>*@
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="leave in list">
                                    <td width="14%">{{leave.date}}</td>
                                    <td width="20%">{{leave.monthCode}}</td>
                                    <td>{{leave.holiday_name}}</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Converting date is doesn't matter I wrote custom filter and method for that so I can get expected date format by using this filter and method:

```
app.filter('jsonDate', function () {
    return function (date) {
        return new Date(date.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
    }
})

$scope.dateFormat = function (date) {
        $scope.formattedDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (((date.getMonth() + 1).length) == 2 ? (date.getMonth() + 1) : ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1))) + "-" + ((date.getDay().length) == 2 ? date.getDay() : ("0" + date.getDay()));
        return $scope.formattedDate
    }
```

Current output:

```
/Date(1484397151447)/   1   pongal
/Date(1484310751447)/   1   Bhogi
/Date(1483273951447)/   1   new year
/Date(1494855933060)/   5   may day
```

Can any one tell me that how should I loop to get expected format.

Comment: can you able to post your data

Comment: What are you currently getting for the output?

Comment: @nipuna777 check updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just directly access the object: (I am assuming that the month is defined in each array item)

```
<table ng-repeat="list in holidayList" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{list[0].month}}</td>
        </td>
        <tr ng-repeat="leave in list">
            <td width="14%">{{leave.date}}</td>
            <td width="20%">{{leave.monthCode}}</td>
            <td>{{leave.holiday_name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

---

If month is not defined then use javascript array for months:

```
$scope.months = ["Jan", "February, "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
```

Then on your html:

```
<td>{{months(list[0].monthCode - 1)}}</td>
```

or just `list[0].monthCode` if monthCode starts with 0 for Jan.